# How to increase admin log out time

Tags: admin, session, magento2.3.3

I have tried but not working.

To increase session to time for Admin  :

> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Security -> Admin
>   Session Lifetime (it must be in seconds).

Uncheckd uses System value option and add your value in the textbox.

The Minimumm second is 60 and the Maximum is 31536000 (for one year).

Refer below screenshot for more details.
Can you please help how to increase session log out time.

Comment: Have you run cache flush command after it?

Comment: yes. I have run setup: upgrade static-content:deploy and cache flush. all run

Comment: Try after removing browser cookie and cache.

Comment: Yes, but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Check your php configuration for the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value, it must be equals or greater than you set in settings.

Comment: Still not working